# How to transform PayPal Classic Payment form into PayPal REST API PHP Application?

Tags: php, api, rest, paypal

The following is the simplest PayPal interface form:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" /> 
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" /> 
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="JohnDoe2@example.com" /> 
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Purchase at the Virtual Store" /> 
  <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Organic-001" />
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="17.4" /> 
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR" /> 
  <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.example.com/paypalnotify.php" /> 
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Pay now By PayPal" />
</form>
```

This form is specific to a PayPal premier business account and a given amount to pay, with following key parameters:

1. business=JohnDoe2@example.com.
2. amount=17.4EUR.
3. currency_code=EUR or USD.
4. notify_url as the callback for PayPal.com as it ends.

By clicking on the [submit] button, it perfoms this:

1. It redirects the customer to the paypal.com site.
2. The user will login into her/his PayPal account, and validate the payment.
3. The PayPal site will call the paypalnotify.php like a callback, passes information indicating if the payment has suceeded, cancelled, or not valid...

Now in the new interface using PalPal REST API, using [PHP development kit](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php), how one has to proceed to accomplish the payment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options. Start by looking at the code in these files:

https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/blob/master/sample/payments/CreatePayment.php
https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/blob/master/sample/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.php

Obviously they don't have any interactive forms, but they show the general process. Dig in and work through creating your code. Then when you hit problems, open a new question with the specific issues. StackOverflow is not for "how do I" type questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic